# CryptoControl - Python Crypto News API Integration in Python Django

Tags: python, django, rest, api, pypi

My code is--

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from crypto_news_api import CryptoControlAPI

def index(request):

   api = CryptoControlAPI("i have entered my api key")  

   api.enableSentiment()

   # Get top news
   topNews = api.getTopNews(language = "en")
   print(topNews)
   #return render(request, 'index.html',{"data":topNews})
```

I am integrating `CryptoControl` - Python Crypto News API in django but i am getting this error:

```
Bad response from the CryptoControl API
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.2.3
Exception Type: Exception
Exception Value:    
Bad response from the CryptoControl API
Exception Location: C:\Users\sachin.parashar\Envs\newsbit\lib\site-packages\crypto_news_api\__init__.py in _fetch, line 28
Python Executable:  C:\Users\sachin.parashar\Envs\newsbit\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
```

Can anyone help me on this as I am new to python with django framework.
Also I have installed -- `pip install crypto-news-api`
and `pip install requests`.

Comment: show your code and setting

Comment: edit your post not here dear.

Comment: Can you please check it now.

Comment: Nothing error with your code , it might be from their api . Try to send request using curl or postman and see

Comment: curl "https://cryptocontrol.io/api/v1/public/news/coin/bitcoin" \
  -H "x-api-key: API_KEY_HERE"

Comment: i am getting data in postman with this url -- "cryptocontrol.io/api/v1/public/news/coin/bitcoin" \ -H "x-api-key: API_KEY_HERE" but when i am running the particular function then it's saying 404 not found in postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
data= requests.get("__You URL__")
data_content= json.loads(data.content)
return render(request, '__you template here__', 'data':data_content})
```